# trigger creation gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i have sql server management studio 2012 and im trying to create a trigger on an existing database, to test this i created a table "prueba" and im trying to set a trigger (by right clicking the database, calle veritrax and hitting "new query"). this is my query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER items_insert ON [dbo.prueba]
FOR INSERT
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(WEBDB, 'SELECT * FROM prueba')
SELECT ID, Name FROM INSERTED

GO
```

however, i'm getting this error:

*Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure items_insert, Line 1
The object 'dbo.prueba' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.*

what is wrong with the query? any help would be appreciated

EDIT: Oh god, sorry i pasted an old error message, the error made reference to prueba.dbo not tlbAccessAreas!

Comment: Check if dbo.prueba that has any dependencies on dbo.tblAccessAreas. Check if dbo.prueba has any FKs with tblAccessAreas. Any other triggers on dbo.prueba accessing dbo.tblAccessAreas.

Comment: how would i check this? im new to sql server, i doubt it has dependencies because i especifically created the table to test a linked server!

Comment: If you have the right permissions, you can right-click on the dbo.prueba table and click `View Dependencies`

Comment: oh ok, thx, it has no dependencies!. So why does the query not work?

Comment: I am not able to follow what is your objective with this trigger? `Insert INTO OPENQUERY` synatx is incorrect. It looks like you want to insert into prueba whenever there is data inserted into prueba? Can you please explain what do you want to accomplish and then we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I'm surprised nobody spotted it. Your dotted notation is not correct, i.e.: `[dbo.prueba]` should be `[dbo].[prueba]`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER items_insert ON [dbo].[prueba]
FOR INSERT
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY(WEBDB, 'SELECT * FROM prueba')
    SELECT ID, Name FROM INSERTED
GO
```